# nhibernate how to find bad field in complex update

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am saving a complex object tree back to my sql server database.
one of the fields on the object tree must be a `null` or a funny date because I get this error message.

> *"SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and
>   12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM."*

I can find it by using visual studios inspector and drill down until I find the dodgy field, but this is very time consuming. Also it doesn't led itself to a great logging error message.

Is their a way I can get nhibernate to return the offending field name with the error message?

I am not doing anything fancy,

```
public TEntity Save(TEntity entity)
    {
        return Save(entity, false);
    }
```

note: I am using fluent nhibernate to configure

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate won't tell you which field caused this, but it's easy to narrow it down: with 99% certainty, it's a **non-nullable** `DateTime` field that you have not initialized, so it has the default value of 1/1/1 (IIRC), which is clearly outside the range.

Comment: sure. but my object tree has many of these fields. so its a pain to have to drill down to keep finding it. it is almost certainly due to some bad data I inherited somewhere along the line and it would make my life so much easier if i could just jump straight to the field

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for SQL Server, but with SQLite, the name of the offending field is often shown, but buried so deeply in the exception message or inner exceptions that it is very easy to miss.

It may be valuable to simply call the exception's ToString() method, which will create a single string containing all message text, including all inner exceptions, and show it in a message box.

Or, type the following in the Immediate Window, e.g.

```
Debug.Print( ex.ToString() )
```

When you can see it all at once, you may find what you need buried in the middle somewhere.